# How do I keep an image window open that I wrote in Visual studio SDL?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, sdl-2

I installed recently sdl2 of visual studio but I'm having problems when I have to load an image.
Practically the window closes immediately without regard to whether the image is loaded.
I used the code on lazyfoo.net.

Can you help me?

http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/02_getting_an_image_on_the_screen/index.php

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behaviour, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the expected behaviour. SDL does not somehow automatically keep a window open when `main` ends – why should it, anyway? If you want your window to remain open, then you need some kind of **loop** in `main`.

Just go on to the [next chapter in the tutorial](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/03_event_driven_programming/index.php). It will explain the looping mechanism in detail. The loop will be of the form:

> ```
> //While application is running
> while( !quit ) {
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: I noticed that the problem has persisted and tend to be poor in visual studio that does not support very well sdl I moved all my laovor of codeblocks order to feel comfortable.I thank you for the help